# How to customize work area / admin area in a custom post type without plugins?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-field

Strangely I don't find much sources on the web talking about my desires. So I hope it is a trivial thing I'm asking (although I fear it's not and Wordpress is just..).

Naturally I need custom fields in my custom post types.

Wordpress' native way of handling custom fields is very inconvenient and I can't expect my clients to deal with these dropdowns, adding fields as they need it–

So far I manage my custom fields with the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin.

I wanna understand how to do this on my own and therefore hope for more flexibility in customizing the work area / admin area of the "new post" and "edit post" pages.

There must be a way to set custom fields in code and influence how the inputs are accessible on the admin page.

Providing a simple example, I want to add a quicklink-feature to the page, where the admin can add posts containing nothing but a title and a url (I'm aware of the native "Links" area and purposely avoid using it)

So far I made a simple one-file-plugin containing the declaration for the custom post type:

```
<?php

    /*
    Plugin Name: Got Nexxt Quicklinks 
    Plugin URI: none
    Description: Quicklinks custom post type + special admin area
    Author: René Eschke
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://www.eschke.info/
    */

    function my_custom_post_quicklinks() {
      $labels = array(
          'name'               => _x( 'Quicklinks', 'post type general name' ),
          'singular_name'      => _x( 'Quicklink', 'post type singular name' ),
          'add_new'            => _x( 'Hinzuf&uuml;gen', 'book' ),
          'add_new_item'       => __( 'Quicklink hinzuf&uuml;gen' ),
          'edit_item'          => __( 'Quicklink bearbeiten' ),
          'new_item'           => __( 'Neue Quicklink' ),
          'all_items'          => __( 'Alle Quicklinks' ),
          'view_item'          => __( 'Quicklink ansehen' ),
          'search_items'       => __( 'Quicklink durchsuchen' ),
          'not_found'          => __( 'Kein Quicklink gefunden' ),
          'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Keine Quicklinks im Papierkorb gefunden' ), 
          'parent_item_colon'  => '',
          'menu_name'          => 'Quicklinks'
      );
      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-links',
        'description' => 'Quicklinks sind vor allem für Shortcuts zu bestimmten Podcast-positionen da',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title'), 
        'has_archive' => false,
      );
      register_post_type('quicklink', $args);
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_quicklinks' );

?>
```

Again: 
**I want to implement this myself all in code without using a plugin.**

Thanks!

[image: done with Advanced Custom Fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a totally customizable solution.
The general approach illustrated by LWS-mo remains the same.
But instead of using `add_meta_box()` I used **`add_post_meta()`**

`add_meta_box()` requires a callback function that prints out the HTML. Using `add_post_meta()` a callback has to be hooked in manually.

The key action hook here is **`edit_form_after_editor`**. (Actually there are a lot of hooks for the admin-work-area [> WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request))

---

Another important insight I had:
All these **changes apply to every post type** unless you return the functions when the post type differs your desired one. Therefore I made a helper-function, which needs to be called first thing in the action hooks.

Furthermore I skipped calling function names in the `add_action` function and used anonymous functions as parameter. I find this way more convenient; *please correct me if I miss something bigger here.*

Here's the code in short version:

```
// helper function to prevent editing other post types than desired
function is_my_posttype() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "my_custom_posttype") return true;
    else return false;
}

// create custom post type
add_action("init", function() {
    $labels = ... 
    $args = ...
    register_post_type("my_custom_posttype", $args); 
});

// add custom fields 
add_action("add_meta_boxes", function() {
    if (!is_my_posttype()) return;
    add_post_meta($post->ID, "url", "", true); // true creates a unique custom field; no initial value needed
    add_post_meta(...)
    // create as many as you need
});

// insert the html in both ADD and EDIT forms
// $post parameter required
add_action("edit_form_after_editor", function( $post ) {
    if (!is_my_posttype()) return;

    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'my_custom_nonce' ); // to check for later in save function 

    $stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

    // now do whatever magic you want; 
    // it gets inserted straight below the editor
    // without any wrapping html cage
    ?> 
        <label ...>Some Label</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php if (isset($stored_meta["url"])) echo $stored_meta["url"][0]; ?>" />
        Add even more
    <?php
});

// make the custom fields savable 
add_action("save_post", function( $post_id )) {
    if (!is_my_posttype()) return;

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'my_custom_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'my_custom_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "url", $_POST["url"]);
    update_post_meta( ... )
    // update all the other post metas 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for "meta boxes".

You will work with `add_meta_box()` to **create** one or multiple new meta-boxes for your post-types. ([Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/))

You have to set up some **callback function** which holds the HTML of the fields you want to show/display.

And you will also need a function to **save** these fields using `add_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()`. (Codex to [ADD](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) and [UPDATE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta))

If you want to **remove** some existing meta-boxes you can use `remove_meta_box()`. ([Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box))

---

**Some Details:**

With the following code you can create a new Meta-box on the new/edit screen of your "quicklinks" post-type. (cause I entered "quicklink" as the post-type)

```
function create_custom_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'my_meta', // HTML 'id' attribute of the metabox
        __( 'My Setting', 'textdomain' ), // Title of metabox
        'my_fields_callback', // Function that prints out the HTML for metabox
        'quicklink', // The post-type of writing screen on which to show the edit screen section (example 'post' or 'page')
        'normal', // The part of the page where the metabox should be shown ('normal', 'advanced', or 'side')
        'high' // The priority within the context where the boxes should show ('high', 'core', 'default' or 'low')
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'create_custom_metabox' );
```

After this code you will already see a new Meta-Box, but it will be empty, there are no fields yet to show.

So next we create a new callback function with our new fields: (see function name and callback argument in `add_meta_box()` above)

```
function my_fields_callback( $post ) {

    // creating a custom nonce
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'my_custom_nonce' );

    // see and get if some meta is already saved
    $stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

    ?>
    <!-- Textfield START -->
    <p>
        <span class="my-row-title">
            <label for="meta-text" class="my-row-title"><?php _e( 'Text', 'textdomain' )?></label>
        </span>
        <div class="my-row-content">
            <input type="text" name="meta-text" id="meta-text" placeholder="Text..." value="<?php if ( isset ( $stored_meta['meta-text'] ) ) echo $stored_meta['meta-text'][0]; ?>" />

        </div>
    </p>
    <!-- Textfield END -->

<?php
}
```

After this code, you will already see a new input field and a label. But if you enter something it will still not get saved! So we need to add a save function to this:

```
function save_my_meta( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'my_custom_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'my_custom_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }


    // save our new created field
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) ) {
        // if there is some content in the field, we update it
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-text', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta-text' ] ) );
    }


}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_meta' );
```

After that we can save the values of your new field.

If you want to show these values you can use the `get_post_meta()` function. ([Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)) like this:

```
$my_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-text', true );

if( !empty( $my_meta_value ) ) {
    echo $my_meta_value;
}
```

So, you see there are several functions needed. There are a lots of tutorials out there, [here is an old one which still functions.](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/)

I couldnt find one in german in the moment, sorry.

Be also sure to have an eye an sanitize the different values of the fields on saving and retrieving.

I hope this helps!

---

**Update:**

When you create a meta-box with the `add_meta_box()` function, you can set where the meta-box should appear with the context parameter...

```
add_meta_box( 
            'my_meta', 
            __( 'My Setting', 'textdomain' ), 
            'my_fields_callback', 
            'quicklink',
            'normal', // The part of the page where the metabox should be shown ('normal', 'advanced', or 'side')
            'high'
        );
```

If you choose **side**, the box will be created on the right sidebar.

**Regarding ACF and fields without the wrapper container:**

It seems when you create an field with ACF without the meta-box-wrapper/container, some elements are just hidden, and some extra styles are added to hide the container!

So I think the best way would be to load some custom css and maybe jQuery, *only* on the edit/new page of the post-type which has your custom fields.

```
function add_scripts_and_styles()
{
    global $typenow;
    if( 'quicklink' != $typenow )
        return;         

    echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $('#my_meta').removeClass('postbox');
        $('#my_meta h3').hide();
    });     
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
    /* CUSTOM RULES */
</style>
";
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'add_scripts_and_styles' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'add_scripts_and_styles' );
```

[**Source: This Stackexchange answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459485/4792216)

---

**Nonces:**
I try to explain it, but maybe the codex will be clearer to you:

A nonce in the WP envoirnment is a security feature.
Its a random and unique combination of numbers and letters which is only valid a limited time and also per user.

In this case we are using it in the form to check that the input-data are coming from the genuine user.
The system will check the nonce upon saving to see that nobody/something else is trying to save the data.

Or as the codex says it:

> The nonce field is used to validate that the contents of the form request came from the current site and not somewhere else.

You can read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) about nonces.

Comment: Although this comes close to what I'm looking for the question is not fully answered yet. `add_meta_box()` gives ma a new box per new setting; what if I don't want the box? I'd like to print out the HTML just like Advanced Custom Fields does it; plain without any other HTML wrapping around it.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some infos and a link on how you **could** do it. I could not find another way to do this.

Comment: All info I find in your post is `add_meta_box()` related; Sure you edited? The tutorial you posted ("old one which still funcitons") also goes the meta_box-route.

Comment: Could you explain why you used `wp_nonce_field()` in your example?

Comment: Yes I edited my first post with an update, to let you know how you can set the position of the new meta_box, and also how you could hide the container.

As you said my answer is only related to `add_meta_box()`, because this seems to be the only way to create them. (using default WP-code)
So my update was about how you can **hide** the container around your new fields.

Comment: I extended my answer once again with a short text about nonces. I find it kind of hard to explain, I hope it helps. But you should check out the official codex entries to understand/discover some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51597/discussion-between-kater-louis-and-lws-mo).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a *custom meta box*

You will need [add_meta_box()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes), take a look.
Also here is a nice tutorial which deals with the basics:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

Comment: This is an example I stumbled upon in my research. And it only makes custom meta boxes happening in the sidebar–